# How do I get MsBuild to use a specific compiler?

Tags: compilation, msbuild

We're moving to Visual Studio 2012, and want to make sure all our programs work well with it.  I've tested a C# program extensively, and want the production version to use VS 2012.

We're doing the production builds with CruiseControl, and that is using MsBuild.exe to build .NET programs.  The XML and parameters in use don't mention which compiler version, and when looking at the build output I can't tell which compiler is used.  (The build servers have VS 2008, VS 2010, and VS 2012 available.)

When I double-clicked on the solution file, it came up in VS 2010, regardless of whether I'd last used 2010 or 2012 to open and compile it.  I was able to change that by looking at the first two lines of the solution file in a text editor:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
```

and changing the 2010 to 2012.

To make sure CruiseControl/MsBuild compiles it with the 2012 compiler, can I just do the change above?  Should I do it?  Is there a better way?

Comment: It probably depends how Cruise Control is configured to find MSBuild. Unless you're up to some really tricky stuff, you should not notice a problem moving onto the next compiler, I pushed over 550 prohects from 2010 - 2012 without any problems. Also, if you just use 2012 locally you can test on your dev machine.

Answer (score 0):

If CruiseControl is using msbuild.exe to compile your solution and you wish to use a specific version of the MsBuild ToolSet, look at the msbuild.exe /toolsversion (/tv) switch, which would override any project-specific version settings in your .csproj files (e.g. `<Project ToolsVersion="3.5" ...`)